# Resizing elements in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im taking my baby steps in web development and to start with Im learning Twitter Bootstrap. Im using the jumbotron template from the examples and I wanted to include these elements which are at http://bootsnipp.com/snipps/crowdfunding-grid But when I copy and paste the code in my template the elements are zoomed up and covering the whole page. How can I resize them as they are seen on the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These elements have a class called `span3`, the CSS associated to this class helps it resize to the desired width.

In this case, the size that is attributed to `.span3` is a percentage of the parent ul that has a class called `thumbnails`, which results in the size you see on that example.

Comment: tried changing that, makes no difference. My container itself is covering the whole page!

Comment: Yes! you're right! Thank you very much. how do i resize it? im using margin property but, thats not working very well.

Comment: Bootstrap works with predefined sizes based on the 16 grid. So, the size of the so called "span" classes, varies depending on the number in front of the class name. Each number represents one measure from the grid. Read the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html